# Errno::EMFILE (Too many open files - socket(2)) when using RedisStore for caching while running in Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, redis, passenger

My application is using the redis store, which works fine locally, but in production, using Phusion Passenger (open source) I run into this error.

```
Errno::EMFILE (Too many open files - socket(2)):
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.0/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:24:in `initialize'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.0/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:24:in `initialize'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.0/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:143:in `new'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.0/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:143:in `connect_addrinfo'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.0/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:187:in `block in connect'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.0/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:185:in `each'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.0/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:185:in `each_with_index'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.0/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:185:in `connect'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.0/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:260:in `connect'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.0/lib/redis/client.rb:336:in `establish_connection'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.0/lib/redis/client.rb:101:in `block in connect'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.0/lib/redis/client.rb:293:in `with_reconnect'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.0/lib/redis/client.rb:100:in `connect'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.0/lib/redis/client.rb:364:in `ensure_connected'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.0/lib/redis/client.rb:221:in `block in process'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.0/lib/redis/client.rb:306:in `logging'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.0/lib/redis/client.rb:220:in `process'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.0/lib/redis/client.rb:120:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.0/lib/redis.rb:862:in `block in get'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.0/lib/redis.rb:58:in `block in synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.0/lib/redis.rb:58:in `synchronize'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.0/lib/redis.rb:861:in `get'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-store-1.1.7/lib/redis/store/interface.rb:5:in `get'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-store-1.1.7/lib/redis/store/marshalling.rb:17:in `get'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/cache/redis_store.rb:230:in `block in read_entry'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/cache/redis_store.rb:212:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/cache/redis_store.rb:212:in `with'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/cache/redis_store.rb:230:in `read_entry'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/cache.rb:413:in `block in exist?'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/cache.rb:547:in `block in instrument'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/cache.rb:547:in `instrument'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/cache.rb:412:in `exist?'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/cache/redis_store.rb:200:in `exist?'
```

My cache initialization code is

```
Rails.application.configure do
    Rack::MiniProfiler.config.storage_options = { host: 'redis.local.com', port: 6379 }
    Rack::MiniProfiler.config.storage = Rack::MiniProfiler::RedisStore
    config.cache_store = :redis_store, http://redis.local.com:6379, { expires_in: 5.minutes }
    Rails.cache = ActiveSupport::Cache::RedisStore.new
end
```

Having searched all over the redis-rb and redis-store gems, hasn't turned up anything at all. 
How do I ensure passenger does not create multiple connections to Redis when using it as cache store?

Answer (score -1):

This is not a Passenger problem. This is your application hitting its file descriptor limit. Why is it hitting its limit? No idea -- maybe it's supposed to open a lot of file descriptors, or maybe you are leaking file descriptors somewhere. One thing you can try is increasing [passenger_app_file_descriptor_ulimit](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/reference/#passenger_app_file_descriptor_ulimit), but that only helps if your app is really supposed to use many file descriptors, as opposed to leaking them. If your app is leaking them then the only thing left is debugging your app is find out where the leaks are from.

Comment: It cannot be the file descriptor limit. Since the cache store is Redis, and so there's no opening of files.

Comment: A "file descriptor" in unix does not only refer to regular files on the filesystem. TCP sockets, which are used to communicate with Redis, are also file descriptors. Plus, the kernel is flatly telling that you are hitting the file descriptor limit (through the EMFILES errror code).  So you are in fact hitting the file descriptor limit.

Comment: How to test and prevent reaching this limit?